# View all data from a GROUP BY statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, group-by

I will demonstrate a simple example of my issue instead of viewing the long sql query from my project.

My example is something like:

```
Select DeliveryAddressID, PickupDate, TotalWeight, count(DeliveryAddressID) AS Packages
From DeliveryDB
Where Date1 >= '10-12-2013' AND Date2 <= '15-12-2013'
Group By  PickupDate, DeliveryAddressID
```

My result will be something like:

http://prntscr.com/1iksoe

What I want to achieve is to get this DeliveryAddressID for ALL 4 packages but still keep the total numbers. This would be something like this.

What I want as expected result:

http://prntscr.com/1iksr7

The reason I want to do this is because in this way i will be able to track the barcode for each package and also be able to track more details.

Cheers :-)

Comment: Don't use images for your expected or actual result. Use the code-button to format it properly. Three advantages: 1. even if the image  on that hoster is deleted this question makes sense 2. we can copy paste it to sql-fiddle to gt sample data 3. we don't have to click on unknown links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most databases, you can do this using window functions:

```
Select DeliveryAddressID, PickupDate, TotalWeight,
       count(DeliveryAddressID) over (partition by PickupDate, DeliveryAddressID) AS Packages
From DeliveryDB
Where Date1 >= '10-12-2013' AND Date2 <= '15-12-2013';
```

This will return the total on all four lines.

EDIT:

You can handle `TotalWeight` (which was not part of the original question) the same way:

```
Select DeliveryAddressID, PickupDate,
       count(DeliveryAddressID) over (partition by PickupDate, DeliveryAddressID) AS Packages,
       CEILING(SUM(CASE When (Weight <> 0 AND Volumen <> 0) AND Weight >= (Volumen * @zeroVoluFac)
                        Then Weight
                   end) over (partition by PickupDate, DeliveryAddressID)
              ) as TotalWeight
From DeliveryDB
Where Date1 >= '10-12-2013' AND Date2 <= '15-12-2013';
```

Comment: Thanks for you respond, but what about totalWeight?
I just did the partition by and seems that my database goes in a very long load mode.
I just want to note that totalWeight is a result from a case statement. Example would be CEILING(SUM(CASE When (Weight != 0 AND Volumen != 0) AND Weight >= (Volumen * @zeroVoluFac) Then Weight") AS TotalWeight

Comment: Thanks alot, will accept your answer, and i will try out from here, I might get back to you i get it to work! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't do quite that, but would you accept total lines after the details instead of zero on the first `N` lines and the total on the last, like this:

```
    IdCode      Weight      PickupDate                  
    ----------- ----------- -------------------------   
    12345       5           2013-01-07 00:00:00.0       
    12345       10          2013-01-07 00:00:00.0     
    12345       15          2013-01-07 00:00:00.0     
    12345       20          2013-01-07 00:00:00.0     
    (4 rows)

    Sum(Weight) Count(IdCode) 
    ----------- ------------- 
    50          4
```

If that's of any use to you, the SQL I used was (sorry about the non-matching column names)

```
Select IdCode, Weight, PickupDate  
From DeliveryDB  
Group By  PickupDate, IdCode  
ORDER BY PickupDate, IdCode  
COMPUTE sum(Weight), count(IdCode)  by PickupDate, IdCode
```

The `COMPUTE` gives totals or other aggregates at the breaks in `Group By`.

Comment: Thanks alot ill try you example and i will get back to you!

Comment: I just found out that it's need to make it look like i do in my example where everything is 0 and last package equals all the data put together.
I also understod that you I can chose the package with for instance the lowest ID number or Highest to be the one to view all the data